# Какой знак препинания поставить вместо?

Tags: пунктуация

Для тех, кто забыл (о призе) ? мы дарим сертификат

Comment: Всё-таки не "для тех", а "тем", наверное.

Comment: Кстати, Вам самой какой знак препинания кажется уместным?

Comment: тем кто забыл о призе, мы дарим сертификат?)) смысл другой. Кажется, что :

Comment: Если сертификат дарят кому-то ещё, а не забывшим о призе, тогда можно и "для"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для спасения этой фразы без изменения падежей можно разбить её двоеточием. Этим можно уклониться от прямого указания (с правильным падежом) на тех, кому дарят. Первая часть будет неполным предложением, поясняющим, *для кого произносится* следующее за этим напоминание.

```
Для тех, кто забыл (о призе) [вот наше напоминание]: мы дарим сертификат.
```

Answer (score 4):

Для тех, кто забыл (о призе) ? мы дарим сертификат.

**Для "спасения этой фразы" ее нужно переделать**, так как семантика сообщения совершенно неясна, а грамматика оставляет желать лучшего (предложение  попросту не читается, так как не имеет нормальной интонационной структуры).

В качестве варианта: И еще раз напомним тем, кто забыл: мы всем дарим  подарочный сертификат!

Comment: Предложение не читается вовсе не из-за интонационной структуры. А из-за неряшливой семантики. Ну, и грамматика тоже не айс... Мне кажется, вы сильно преувеличиваете  роль "интонации", прям-таки ставите ее на первое место. Вот здесь интонация ну абсолютно ни при чем.

Comment: Niemand, вы всегда прочитываете только слово "интонация", а у меня написано "интонационная структура", а это почти что структурная грамматика, а там и до грамматики недалеко. Вот, к примеру, предлагается поставить в предложении двоеточие, а как вы прочитаете это? Должны понизить тон, сделать предупредительную паузу, а после паузы (вместо ожидаемого подробного разъяснения) какой-то текстовый фрагмент малого объема, его-то  как прочесть? Вы вот потренируйтесь, если есть свободное время.

Comment: Вера, хотя и вариант Александра тоже неплохой, но ''спасти ситуацию'' он может разве что на бумаге, т.к. двоеточие явно сигнализирует о том, что здесь предупреждение тем, кто забыл о призе. Ваш вариант намного лучше( и на письме, и в устной речи), но я бы добавил в него слово ''приз'', т.к. именно о призе идет речь. Иначе понять невозможно, кто о чем забыл.

Comment: >> *Вот, к примеру, предлагается поставить в предложении двоеточие, а как вы прочитаете это? Должны понизить тон, сделать предупредительную паузу, а после паузы (вместо ожидаемого подробного разъяснения) какой-то текстовый фрагмент малого объема, его-то как прочесть?*       Допустим, *"А я тебе говорю: ты не прав!"* Законное двоеточие, но никакого "подробного разъяснения". И никакой особой паузы, можно даже совсем без нее. Ваши теории с практикой ну никак не шьются.

Comment: В вашем примере изъяснение, а не пояснение, при этом второе предложение имеет собственную интонацию, это самостоятельное предложение по грамматике и по смыслу. А в примере, который мы разбираем, грамматика самостоятельного предложения, а семантика отдельной фразы, вот оно и не читается. Так я понимаю ситуацию. Также могу добавить, что не стала бы вас утомлять интонационными разъяснениями,  если бы  могла иначе доказать, что предложение составлено неудачно. Вот вы, к примеру, назовете что-то неряшливым, а почему - не объясняете. Я же считаю, что свое мнение нужно доказывать.

Answer (score 0):

Только так:

***Для тех, кто забыл о призе: мы дарим сертификат!***

И предложение  будет восклицательным.

Answer (score 0):

Неграмотная всё же фраза,  в духе нашей " продвинутой" рекламы.
Даже если спасти этот слоган двоеточием, всё равно он нуждается в добавлении слов -  уж хотя бы "мы дарим ВАМ сертификат!" Или "дарим ВСЕМ".

Впрочем, это вся "недосказанность"  делается  и сознательно - народ сейчас переходит на клиповое восприятие, много слов не поймёт и не прочтёт, а неграмотность мало кого смущает.